# Override setText() method in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel

I have the following code implemented in Java.

```
public class FadeLabel extends javax.swing.JLabel {

    private Timer onTimer;

    public FadeLabel() {
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
        onTimer = new Timer(100, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            // animation code
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        onTimer.start();
        super.setText(text);
    }
}
```

When I create an object of this class, it gives a `NullPointerException` in the `setText()` method, the line `onTimer.start()`.

I want to know why is this exception happening..?

ps: **I know what is a `NullPointerException` is. I want to know how is it generated here..**

This is how I instantiate.

```
notificationLabel = new FadeLabel();
```

Comment: You are creating the Label with `new FadeLabel()` ? If you use any other constructor, you would not create a new Timer. That is the only one I could think of right now.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 since there is no other constructor, let's assume he's not using another one

Comment: Show us the code piece where you are actually creating new instance `FabeLabel`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @TT. nope. it's not a duplicate of that. he's asking why the NPE, when the variable is in fact instantiated

Comment: What are the odds that NPE comes actually not from `onTimer.start()` but from null reference to `FadeLabel` like this: `FadeLabel label; label.setText()` ?? :)

Comment: Please add whole stacktrace as I suspect that NPE is not comming from the line you have pointed out.

Comment: @Antoniossss not, since then the NPE would not be thrown in the setText method

Comment: @Stultuske Im saying that OP is mistaken and NPE is not from the line he pointed out. Stacktrace needed.

Comment: @Antoniossss he COULD be mistaken. bit of a difference there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JLabel.java) for `JLabel`

```
public JLabel() {
    this("", null, LEADING);
}

public JLabel(String text, Icon icon, int horizontalAlignment) {
    setText(text);
    setIcon(icon);
    setHorizontalAlignment(horizontalAlignment);
    updateUI();
    setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
}
```

Thus we can see that the no-argument constructor calls the other one, which then calls `setText`.  However at that point your `init` method hasn't run, so `onTimer` is still `NULL`.

Comment: This is then a good illustration why calling non-final methods in a constructor is an anti-pattern...

Comment: This is why netbeans gives warning when calling an overridable methods in the constructor..

Answer (score -3):

You define the property onTimer. You have a method init. You must call it to instantiate the timer property onTimer.

Comment: According to the code shown he is doing that during no-args construction.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.